# toUpperCase inside ngOnInit

Tags: angular, ionic3

I want to change the values when I receive the data from the provider.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.recapServiceProvider.getRecapPremevementt().subscribe(data => {
      this.recap = data;
      this.recap.forEach(element => {
        this.recap.type=element.type.toUpperCase();       
        console.log(this.recap.type);
      });
      console.log(this.recap);
    });
  }
```

When I try to console the "`console.log(this.recap.type)`", it shows me that the type is in upper case but on the dom and on the second `console.log(this.recap)` nothing changes.

How I can resolve that problem ?

Comment: Can you show the `html code`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a built in Pipe for that

```
{{recap.type| uppercase}}
```

Comment: on the html, I have this bloc  <div *ngIf=" op.type =='ABCD'  > sometimes i receive the type in lower case and i can't use the uppercase inside the ngIf

Comment: can you try this :   *ngIf="(op.type | uppercase) === 'ABCD'"

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for.

```
this.recapServiceProvider.getRecapPremevementt()
        .map(data => data.map(el => el.type.toUpperCase()))
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
    });
```